# How JQUERY and JQM causing CORS error?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, cors

I have a HTML5 page without any Jquery that does not have any CORS error as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<button type="button" onClick="getBase64FromImageUrl()">Click Me!</button>
<img id="preview1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e39d18b89822d1d9871e0d1bc839d06?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                function getBase64FromImageUrl() {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img =  document.getElementById("preview1");
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.width =img.width;
                    canvas.height =img.width;
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    alert(  dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")); 
                }
    </script>
    </HTML>
```

This code is able to return base64 image data and Working fine.

Once I add Jquery and JQM on it , it return CORS Error , The code as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">/script>         
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />

<button type="button" onClick="getBase64FromImageUrl()">Click Me!</button>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search ..." id="Pro">
                <li id="1">                 
                    <a> 
                    <img id="preview1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e39d18b89822d1d9871e0d1bc839d06?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
                    <h2>Warning</h2>
                    <p>Hot</p>
                    </a>    
                </li>
            </ul>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
            function getBase64FromImageUrl() {
                var img = new Image();
                img =  document.getElementById("preview1");
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width =img.width;
                canvas.height =img.width;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                alert(  dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")); 
            }
</script>
</HTML>
```

After included Jquery and JQM i am not able to get base64 image data , because of CORS error for jquery, the error message is below

```
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy. jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3
```

I have no idea why once include the CORS error happen . In my Server side i have included the header for allowing origin `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Answer (score 0):

CORS error is caused by the fact that image you're trying to load into Canvas object comes from another domain and once you've done so your canvas object is tainted.

**Solution:** server sending image should include cross-origin header allowing your domain to access information.

**Mode info**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image

Comment: I am aware of the problem . but i have allow cross origin header . please have a clear look at the question

Comment: You're right - there's a header in image response. The problem is that when jquery is included `origin` header is not sent. If you move `<script>` tag to bottom of your page everything works. I admit, it's not perfect solution, but for starters it should do, especially since it's getting more common to place js at the bottom (i.e. HTMLBoilerplate).

Comment: If I move the jquery to bottom , there is another problem is whenevery my other java script have $ will hit problem. And if have any script that add image attribute Img.setAttribute('crossorigin','anonymous') will happen the same problem