# Trying to implement rainyday.js with a local image rather than a web image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i'm trying to implement the rainyday.js into a project i'm working on however I have no experience with Javascript so i'm struggling.

Basically the code currently calls an online image (from imgur) and this works fine. But when I try and call a local image it does not display the effect, just the local image.

Is there any easy way to make this code call a local image rather than a web image?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>rainyday.js</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/animation.css"/>
        <script src="../misc/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="rainyday.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function run() {
                var image = document.getElementById('background');
                image.onload = function() {
                    var engine = new RainyDay({
                        image: this
                    });
                    engine.rain([ [3, 3, 0.88], [5, 5, 0.9], [6, 2, 1] ], 100);
                };
                image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
                image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/f7bpv.jpg';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="run();">
        <div class="rainWrapper1">
        <img id="background" alt="background" src="" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

A link to the JS on Github:

https://github.com/maroslaw/rainyday.js/blob/master/rainyday.js

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How your image url looks like?

Comment: Good question: my images are stored in a folder so the image url is 'images/thisisanimage.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it in Firefox? It works for me there, however in Chrome the js execution is denied by the error "Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy." This means, that the Server you're using (i.e. none) does not send a valid cross-origin header. See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047640/how-jquery-and-jqm-causing-cors-error/20051607?noredirect=1#20051607). If you're just using this for development you can start chrome with the flag `--disable-web-security` which should allow you to circumvent same origin policy. Otherwise you will have to run a server supporting CORS somewhere.